# Beamer/LaTeX boxes

Tags: beamer, technical-drawing

How I can draw docs and figures in latex (or beamer) like on picture?
[image]

Comment: Hello! Have you made any progress so far, and if so, can you post that code?

Comment: Welcome! Can you post the code you've got so far? What have you tried? Perhaps you have the content in the form of a table or list? Whatever you have, please provide it as your question is currently in danger of being closed since draw-it-for-me is not always considered reasonable on this site.

Comment: Please DO **NOT** VOTE TO CLOSE a question within 10 minutes of its being posted by a new user. Admittedly, the question could be improved and should be. But there is time and enough to close it if that doesn't happen. Moreover, voting to close without leaving any comment or explanation at all is particularly obnoxious. At least say hello and explain how the question might be improved! (And there is disagreement about whether draw-it-for-me questions should ever be closed for that reason. But especially for first questions.)

Comment: PGF/TikZ is one possibility. Or `tcolorbox`. Or... Do you want this for Beamer or a regular article/report/book? Because a Beamer solution might need to look different, though not necessarily, and an example document would be especially useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something to start:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning, shapes.arrows}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small,
    yellow/.style={minimum width=1.5cm, fill=yellow, draw=orange, minimum height=5mm},
    gray/.style={minimum width=.5cm, fill=gray, draw,  minimum height=5mm},
    orange/.style={minimum width=1.5cm, fill=orange!70, draw=orange, minimum height=5mm,},
    pink/.style={minimum width=.5cm, fill=pink!70, draw=pink,  minimum height=5mm},
    ]

    \matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
    nodes={gray, anchor=center}, 
    column sep=1pt, row sep=3pt, 
    column 1/.style={nodes=yellow}
]
    {
    blue &|[label=1]| &|[label=2]| 1 &|[label=3]| &|[label=4]| \\
    cat & & & 1 & \\
    egg & & & & 1 \\
    fish & 1& 1 & & \\
    green & & & & 1 \\
    ham & & & & 1 \\
    hat & & & 1 & \\
    one & 1& & & \\
    red & & 1 & & \\
    two & 1& & & \\
    };

    \matrix (B) [matrix of nodes, 
    nodes={pink, anchor=center}, 
    column sep=3mm, row sep=3pt, 
    column 1/.style={nodes=orange},
    right=3cm of A.south east, anchor=south west
]
    {
    blue & 2 \\
    cat & 3 \\
    egg & 4 \\
    fish & 1& 2 \\
    green & 4 \\
    ham &  4 \\
    hat & 3  \\
    one & 1 \\
    red & 2 \\
    two & 1 \\
    };

    \foreach \i in {1,...,10}
        \draw[->] (B-\i-1)--(B-\i-2);
    \draw[->] (B-4-2)--(B-4-3);

    \path (A-5-5.west) -- node[anchor=east, single arrow, draw=yellow!80!black, fill=yellow!30] {\phantom{right}} (B-5-1.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```